# In angular, how to populate webAPI XML data into autocomplete component of material and how to select the name, but ONLY send it's PK back

Tags: angular, xml, autocomplete, angular-material

How to get Filter autocomplete material to filter with webAPI. In the documentation in the example the data is hardcoded as an array:

https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

this is the example component of the documentation that I am trying to get to work:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-filter-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-filter-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['autocomplete-filter-example.css'],
})
export class AutocompleteFilterExample implements OnInit {
  myControl = new FormControl();
  options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
  filteredOptions: Observable<string[]>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.filteredOptions = this.myControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(value => this._filter(value))
      );
  }

  private _filter(value: string): string[] {
    const filterValue = value.toLowerCase();

    return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
  }
}
```

I am stuck on the part on where return the filter data:

```
 return this.options.filter(option => option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
```

in the example option is hardcoded as an array of strings:

```
 options: string[] = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];
```

My data is coming from an API:

```
  getTeamTask() {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.baseUrl+'tTaskTeams');
  }
```

And I am trying to get it this way:

```
return this.service.getTeamTask().filter(option=> option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue));
```

The filter option keeps coming up with this error: 
Property 'filter' does not exist on type 'Observable'.ts(23

Which I think has to do with the way I am getting my data.

this is an example of my XML coming from my API:
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
<ArrayOftTaskTeam xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ReportingWebAPI">
<tTaskTeam>
<TeamName>GLS - GEEPE all</TeamName>
<isReport>true</isReport>
<pk_TaskTeam>1</pk_TaskTeam>
<sequence>42</sequence>
<tTasks/>
</tTaskTeam>
```

How do I get it to only display the TeamName, and once the item is select in autocomplete field, how do I get it to send the PK back? That is a concept I am confused on too.

Answer (score 0):

```
http.get()
```

returns an observable.  Therefore your code:

```
this.service.getTeamTask()
```

returns an observable, so you'll need to subscribe to it instead of just calling .filter directly.  Something like this:

```
this.service.getTeamTask().pipe( 
     map(options => options.filter(option=> option.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue))
 )
 .subscribe( results => console.log('Filtered options:', results))
```

Comment: I tried that, but that still doesn't seem to work. Do I need to maybe convert obserable to an array and do it that way?
I got the error:  "Type 'Observable<{}>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 25 more.ts("

Comment: Tried something different and saw this post. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49930345/angular-5-with-material-autocomplete
It kind of answers my question